# Programming a GUI for a Vocabulary Tester in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, kivy

I created a vocabulary tester using python 3 in which you can put vocabulary in a foreign language and it will test you every day and learn how you remember in order to calculate the next time it will ask you.
It works great but the only issue is that it runs in the python terminal and I would like to create a GUI. It's a part of programming that I never learned and I think it could be very interesting.

So, here is my question: which python library should I use? I've searched on the Internet and I found websites about Kivy, Pygame, Tkinter but I don't know which one is the best suited.
The things I would like it to do are:
- take input from the user to test the vocabulary learned
- display the answer
- display evolution graphs (I already did that with matplotlib but I would like to add it to the GUI)
- display all the words to allow the user to scroll through them to delete or modify them
- take input from the user to add vocabulary to the file.

That's all I can think of for the minute. I'm not an expert when it comes to programming but I learn quite fast. I guess they will have to be a menu page for the user to choose whether to play, to modify or to add.

Thanks in advance.

Pierre

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't tried all libraries yet, but for this TkInter should do the trick. (and it is easy to learn)

You can use the entry class for input for the users and, labels to display the feedback, etc...

The best thing with TkInter is that there are a lot of data out there, manuals, guides, tutorials and forums. You should have no problem with finding information regarding how to build and tweak your GUI.

Comment: Asking recommendations for offline resources such as libraries, etc., are off-topic in SO, so they should avoid responding, I recommend reading [answer]

Answer (score -2):

I managed to create a fairly complicated game with PyGame in about two weeks, so that's the library that I would suggest. There are lots of resources online (such as the free textbook linked on their website) and plenty of example code to get you started. I've done some stuff with TkInter and I don't like it as much as PyGame, for what that's worth.

Comment: Asking recommendations for offline resources such as libraries, etc., are off-topic in SO, so they should avoid responding, I recommend reading [answer]